# Azure Functions Timer Trigger not working

Tags: azure, azure-functions

My specs:

- Windows 10
- Node 8.9.1
- Runtime BETA 2.0.11390.0 (beta)

Yes, I have installed the VS Code Azure Functions extension and the `CLI` tool with `@beta`.

So, I do `func new --language JavaScript --template TimerTrigger --name testfunc`

which outputs:

```
Select a language: JavaScript
Select a template: TimerTrigger
Function name: [TimerTriggerJS] Writing C:\Users\user\code\azure\functions\testfunc\index.js
Writing C:\Users\user\code\azure\functions\testfunc\readme.md
Writing C:\Users\user\code\azure\functions\testfunc\sample.dat
Writing C:\Users\user\code\azure\functions\testfunc\function.json
```

Then I do `func host start --debug vscode` in the terminal, and I get:

```
                  %%%%%%
                 %%%%%%
            @   %%%%%%    @
          @@   %%%%%%      @@
       @@@    %%%%%%%%%%%    @@@
     @@      %%%%%%%%%%        @@
       @@         %%%%       @@
         @@      %%%       @@
           @@    %%      @@
                %%
                %

[11/29/2017 8:19:39 PM] Reading host configuration file 'C:\Users\user\code\azure\functions\host.json'
[11/29/2017 8:19:39 PM] Host configuration file read:
[11/29/2017 8:19:39 PM] {}
info: Worker.Node.0586fcbb-0c58-48e1-a02e-b0644ace851a[0]
      Start Process: node  --inspect=5858 "C:\Users\user\.azurefunctions\bin\workers\node\dist\src\nodejsWorker.js" --host 127.0.0.1 --port 57233 --workerId 0586fcbb-0c58-48e1-a02e-b0644ace851a --requestId 06b7578c-e1ec-456c-83ee-4c26ce8b9ca3
[11/29/2017 8:19:39 PM] Generating 2 job function(s)
[11/29/2017 8:19:39 PM] Starting Host (HostId=swlaptop2062-377256582, Version=2.0.11370.0, ProcessId=19932, Debug=True, ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=0, FunctionsExtensionVersion=)
[11/29/2017 8:19:39 PM] Found the following functions:
[11/29/2017 8:19:39 PM] Host.Functions.TriggerHR
[11/29/2017 8:19:39 PM] Host.Functions.testfunc
[11/29/2017 8:19:39 PM]
info: Worker.Node.0586fcbb-0c58-48e1-a02e-b0644ace851a[0]
      Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:5858/9e2f7545-9199-4988-b1eb-12d54f999142
info: Worker.Node.0586fcbb-0c58-48e1-a02e-b0644ace851a[0]
      For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Listening on http://localhost:7071/
Hit CTRL-C to exit...
info: Worker.Node.0586fcbb-0c58-48e1-a02e-b0644ace851a[0]
      Worker 0586fcbb-0c58-48e1-a02e-b0644ace851a connecting on 127.0.0.1:57233
launch.json for VSCode configured.
[11/29/2017 8:19:40 PM] Job host started
[11/29/2017 8:19:44 PM] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000FFD4EE60'.
```

So when I POST via POSTMAN `http://localhost:7071/admin/functions/testfunc`, I expect the debugger to fire off and my function to run but nothing happens.

I go to `http://localhost:7071` on my browser and it works. I go to `http://localhost:7071/admin/functions/testfunc` and I get a 404 not found.

What am I doing wrong? I thought I was following all of the right steps.

Comment: What's the difference to your previous question?

Comment: timer triggered should be just that, triggered by timer (or manually in cli via `func run`), yet you're trying to trigger it via postman?

Comment: `func run` does niot work on runtime beta. @Mikhail I am getting a 404.

Comment: @nn2 yes, and you already commented about that in your previous question. I would not create 2 questions for effectively one problem.

Comment: Update: Using the Azure Function tools on VSCode. I created a brand new folder, a new function  app and one new timer trigger. I did `func host start` and still, the POST to `/admin/functions/` still does nothing. I am at a lose.

Comment: @nn2 can you put a repro up on a GitHub repo and share that? Some of the logs (or missing entries) are a bit suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding

```
{
    "input": ""
}
```

in the body of the request, I was able to get the call and debugger working. Yep. That's all that was missing. Now, my VSCode debugger works :-)